# GPT, grub and mdadm. sda drive replaced, raid rebuilt in recovery mode, but now server won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

This is how partition table loooks like:

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  514MB   512MB                      raid
 3      514MB   8706MB  8193MB                     raid
 4      8706MB  2000GB  1992GB                     raid

(parted) 
(parted) quit                                                             
root@condor1958:~# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  514MB   512MB                      raid
 3      514MB   8706MB  8193MB                     raid
 4      8706MB  2000GB  1992GB                     raid
```

Background: I had /dev/sda drive failed and replaced, server was booted into a recovery mode. I did copt partition table from sdb to sda and md synced but now the server doesn't want to boot when I go outside of a recovery mode.

This is the proof that arrays are working in a recovery mode:

```
root@condor1958:/mnt/2/var/log# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md2 : active raid1 sda4[2] sdb4[1]
      1944880960 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[1]
      7996352 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda2[2] sdb2[1]
      499392 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Why server now doesn't want to boot when I exit a recovery mode?

Thanks